# DELETE FROM usando JOIN y LIMIT en MYSQL

Tags: mysql

quiero borrar registros según fecha de una tabla `boleta_archivo`

 Esta tabla no contiene fechas, por lo que hago un JOIN a la tabla `boletas` que si las contiene.
Las enlazo por su clave, y quiero eliminar aquellos registros con fecha anterior a "2021-09-01"

Además quiero ir limitando la cantidad de eliminaciones, por que son muchisimos registros, y la consulta entera no da para el tiempo de conexion. Por eso quiero limitarlos a 100, 1000, 10.000, etc...

Hasta ahora tengo esto, pero me tira errores, de sintaxis, y no entiendo cual es.

```
DELETE FROM `boleta_archivo` c
JOIN `boletas` b
ON c.clave_boleta = b.claveboleta
WHERE b.fecha_emision < "2021-09-01"
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Puede ser porque estas comparando un numero con un string en esta línea `WHERE b.fecha_emision < "2021-09-01"`

Comment: Intenta solo haciendo `WHERE b.fecha_emision < 2021-09-01`

Comment: Y cual seria la diferencia exactamente ??

Comment: btw no es ese el problema, la comparacion no causa problemas.

Answer (score 1):

Según esta sencilla referéncia [mysql delete join](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-join/) deberías realizar algo parecido a esto:

```
DELETE `boleta_archivo` c, `boletas` b
FROM `boleta_archivo` c
JOIN `boletas` b
ON c.clave_boleta = b.claveboleta
WHERE b.fecha_emision < "2021-09-01"
LIMIT 100
```

No sé cómo funcionará en términos de eficiencia pero otra alternativa es:

```
DELETE FROM `boleta_archivo` c
WHERE c.clave_boleta IN 
    (SELECT b.claveboleta FROM `boletas` b WHERE b.fecha_emision < "2021-09-01")
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: No quiero borrar de ambas tablas, solo de C, el resto es la misma consulta.

Comment: La segunda consulta tampoco me sirve, -> `#1235 - Esta versión de MySQL no soporta todavia 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`